# Can't add webparts into a table with 2 columns. SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer

On a custom page, I wanted to place 2 web parts side by side.
I couldn't so I followed through and created a table with two columns.
I tried to drag a web part into either...pretends to and then it places the web part under the table. What am I doing wrong?
Is there another way around?

Answer (score 5):

Create a webpart page and Select below template

[image]

This will give you structure the way you want. ie. 2 column side-by-side

Comment: @Mike Rooker Please accept this as answer if it worked for you